# Hash function errors, c++

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

Here's the simple example class with hash function I wrote. Function maybe isn't most efficient one, but quality of hash function isn't relevant to me for now.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;

class Class{
private:
    int num;
public:
    Class(int n){num=n;}
    Class(){num=0;}
    int getNum(){return num;}

    friend bool operator==(const Class &k1, const Class &k2);

};

bool operator==(const Class &k1, const Class &k2){
    return(k1.num == k2.num);
}

namespace std {
  template <>
  struct hash<Class>{

    size_t operator()(const Class & c) const
    {
        return(31+c.getNum()*7);
    }
  };
}

void main(){

    unordered_set<Class> set;
    set.insert(Class(5));
    set.insert(Class(55));
    set.insert(Class(4));
    set.insert(Class(123));
    set.insert(Class(11));

    for(unordered_set<Class>::iterator it = set.begin(); it!=set.end(); it++)
        cout<<it->getNum()<< endl;
}
```

This worked fine when all fields of `Class` were public, but errors appear in hash function at `return(31+c.getNum()*7);` on `c`, because I can't call `getNum()` function. I don't know if there is any problem if in line `size_t operator()(const Class & c) const` I remove const, so object c is not const?

Also, in the last line, `cout<<it->getNum()<< endl`, there is error when accessing `getNum()` function. I don't know how to iterate over unordered_set `set` and to print num.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator takes a `const` class but calls a non-const member function. To fix your issue declare `getNum` as `const` since it does not modify the class.

```
class Class{
private:
    int num;
public:
    Class(int n) : num(n) {}
    Class() : num(0) {}
    int getNum() const { return num;}

    friend bool operator==(const Class &k1, const Class &k2);

};
```

In the above example also notice that I used [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to instantiate member variables. Also change the return type from `void` to `int` on main and I recommend either returning 0 or `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `<cstdlib>` at the end of main.